# how to print concatenate string in a column in mysql in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

Here is my code, My input is 22/02/2014 22:02:23, here sed command print it as 
  22/02/2014|22.02.23

```
file1=`cat time.txt|sed 's/  */|/g'`
echo $file1
```

But when I print it in table it throws an error in mysql :02:23 is wrong. Is there any way to print whole string in one column?

```
Query="UPDATE env_last_touched set last_touched_datetime=${file1} where cust_name=${customer}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes in your `update sql`:

```
Query="UPDATE env_last_touched set last_touched_datetime='${file1}' where cust_name='${customer}'"
```